# How do I handle files of different lengths / more 'lines'

Tags: xslt-1.0

My problem is, is that my input will have varying lengths / lines. My current code (thanks to michael.hor257k on my previous question) works with my test file, but I'm sure it won't work with files that have more items.

For example:

An input file with 100 records
or
an input file with 2 records.

I am also not sure how to ignore the last record as it is junk created in the original csv file that's converted to the input file.

Input:

```
<csv-xml>
   <record line="1">
      <csv-field-1>1</csv-field-1>
      <csv-field-2>12345</csv-field-2>
      <csv-field-3>7654321</csv-field-3>
      <csv-field-4>1</csv-field-4>
      <csv-field-5>08/08/19</csv-field-5>
      <csv-field-6>08/08/19</csv-field-6>
   </record>
   <record line="2">
      <csv-field-1>2</csv-field-1>
      <csv-field-2>12345</csv-field-2>
      <csv-field-3>12345678</csv-field-3>
      <csv-field-4>3</csv-field-4>
   </record>
   <record line="3">
      <csv-field-1>2</csv-field-1>
      <csv-field-2>12345</csv-field-2>
      <csv-field-3>22345679</csv-field-3>
      <csv-field-4>7</csv-field-4>
   </record>
   <record line="4">
      <csv-field-1>2</csv-field-1>
      <csv-field-2>12345</csv-field-2>
      <csv-field-3>32345680</csv-field-3>
      <csv-field-4>6</csv-field-4>
   </record>
   <record line="5">
      <csv-field-1>2</csv-field-1>
      <csv-field-2>12345</csv-field-2>
      <csv-field-3>42345681</csv-field-3>
      <csv-field-4>2</csv-field-4>
   </record>
   <record line="6">
      <csv-field-1>3</csv-field-1>
      <csv-field-2>12345</csv-field-2>
      <csv-field-3></csv-field-3>
   </record>
</csv-xml>
```

Code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <orders>
        <order>
            <accountNo>
                <xsl:value-of select="csv-xml/record[@line>='1']/csv-field-3"/>
            </accountNo>
            <orderDate>
                <xsl:value-of select="csv-xml/record[@line>='1']/csv-field-5"/>
            </orderDate>
            <orderItems>
                <orderItem>
                    <productCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="csv-xml/record[@line>='2']/csv-field-3"/>
                    </productCode>
                    <Quantity>
                        <xsl:value-of select="csv-xml/record[@line>='2']/csv-field-4"/>
                    </Quantity>
                </orderItem>
                <orderItem>
                    <productCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="csv-xml/record[@line>='3']/csv-field-3"/>
                    </productCode>
                    <Quantity>
                        <xsl:value-of select="csv-xml/record[@line>='3']/csv-field-4"/>
                    </Quantity>
                </orderItem>
                <orderItem>
                    <productCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="csv-xml/record[@line>='4']/csv-field-3"/>
                    </productCode>
                    <Quantity>
                        <xsl:value-of select="csv-xml/record[@line>='4']/csv-field-4"/>
                    </Quantity>
                </orderItem>
                <orderItem>
                    <productCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="csv-xml/record[@line>='5']/csv-field-3"/>
                    </productCode>
                    <Quantity>
                        <xsl:value-of select="csv-xml/record[@line>='5']/csv-field-4"/>
                    </Quantity>
                </orderItem>
            </orderItems>
        </order>
    </orders>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<orders>
<order>
<accountNo>7654321</accountNo>
<orderDate>08/08/19</orderDate>
<orderItems>
<orderItem>
<productCode>12345678</productCode>
<Quantity>3</Quantity>
</orderItem>
<orderItem>
<productCode>22345679</productCode>
<Quantity>7</Quantity>
</orderItem>
<orderItem>
<productCode>32345680</productCode>
<Quantity>6</Quantity>
</orderItem>
<orderItem>
<productCode>42345681</productCode>
<Quantity>2</Quantity>
</orderItem>
</orderItems>
</order>
</orders>
```

The output I want:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<orders><order accountNo="7654321" orderDate="08/08/19">
        <orderItems>
            <orderItem productCode="12345678" quantity="3"/>
            <orderItem productCode="22345679" quantity="7"/>
            <orderItem productCode="32345680" quantity="6"/>
            <orderItem productCode="42345681" quantity="2"/>
        </orderItems>
    </order>
</orders>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/csv-xml">
    <xsl:variable name="header" select="record[1]" />
    <orders>
        <order accountNo="{$header/csv-field-3}" orderDate="{$header/csv-field-5}">
            <orderItems>
                <xsl:for-each select="record[position() != 1 and position() != last()]">
                    <orderItem productCode="{csv-field-3}" quantity="{csv-field-4}"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </orderItems>
        </order>
    </orders>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

P.S. Read about [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates).

Comment: Pretty sure that's magic right there. Thank you so much! I hope this question will help others. I'll make sure to read the Attribute Value Templates